# VBA: replacing array elements

Tags: arrays, vba, element

Edit: based on the comments, I'm providing more details on the code.

The idea of the code is:

There are strings stored in a range B6:E6 (e.g. B6 = "Actual Sales", C6 = "SOP11 (2015)", D6 = "SOP12 (2015)", E6 = "SOP10 (2015)").

I calculate the integer by using "Mid" function if the string is not "Actual Sales".

When that's done, the calculated integers are sorted using BubbleSort in array.

Afterwards, I would like to link the **sorted integers** (SOP_key_B6, SOP_key_C6, SOP_key_D6, SOP_key_E6) with the original string (cell_b6, cell_c6, cell_d6, cell_e6). In other words, there's a one-to-one correspondence between SOP_key_B6 and cell_b6, etc.)

I want to do the above, because I need to input to the range L30:O30 **the sorted array with strings** based on the sorted integers.

I hope this makes the idea clear as it's not very complicated, but the approach itself & code makes it a bit frustrating (probably because I'm still learning the VB coding).

Here's the code:

```
Sub Worksheet_Delta_Update()

'Variables
Dim wb As Workbook, ws_wk_dlt As Worksheet, ws_dash As Worksheet, cell_B6 As  Variant, _
cell_C6 As Variant, cell_D6  As Variant, cell_E6 As Variant, SOP_key_B6 As Variant, _
SOP_key_C6 As Variant, SOP_key_D6 As Variant, SOP_key_E6 As Variant

'Referencing
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws_wk_dlt = wb.Worksheets("t")
Set ws_dash = wb.Worksheets("x")

'Values from pivot stored
cell_B6 = ws_wk_dlt.Range("B6").Value
cell_C6 = ws_wk_dlt.Range("C6").Value
cell_D6 = ws_wk_dlt.Range("D6").Value
cell_E6 = ws_wk_dlt.Range("E6").Value

'If len certain amount of characters then do option 1, or option 2
If cell_B6 <> "" Then
    If Len(cell_B6) = 12 And cell_B6 <> "Actual Sales" Then
            SOP_key_B6 = CInt(Mid(cell_B6, 4, 2)) + CInt(Mid(cell_B6, 8, 4))
    ElseIf Len(cell_B6) = 11 And cell_B6 <> "Actual Sales" Then
        SOP_key_B6 = CInt(Mid(cell_B6, 4, 2)) + CInt(Mid(cell_B6, 7, 4))
    End If
End If

If cell_C6 <> "" Then
    If Len(cell_C6) = 12 And cell_C6 <> "Actual Sales" Then
            SOP_key_C6 = CInt(Mid(cell_C6, 4, 2)) + CInt(Mid(cell_C6, 8, 4))
    ElseIf Len(cell_C6) = 11 And cell_C6 <> "Actual Sales" Then
        SOP_key_C6 = CInt(Mid(cell_C6, 4, 2)) + CInt(Mid(cell_C6, 7, 4))
    End If
End If

If cell_D6 <> "" Then
    If Len(cell_D6) = 12 And cell_D6 <> "Actual Sales" Then
            SOP_key_D6 = CInt(Mid(cell_D6, 4, 2)) + CInt(Mid(cell_D6, 8, 4))
    ElseIf Len(cell_D6) = 11 And cell_D6 <> "Actual Sales" Then
        SOP_key_D6 = CInt(Mid(cell_D6, 4, 2)) + CInt(Mid(cell_D6, 7, 4))
    End If
End If

If cell_E6 <> "" Then
    If Len(cell_E6) = 12 And cell_E6 <> "Actual Sales" Then
            SOP_key_E6 = CInt(Mid(cell_E6, 4, 2)) + CInt(Mid(cell_E6, 8, 4))
    ElseIf Len(cell_E6) = 11 And cell_E6 <> "Actual Sales" Then
        SOP_key_E6 = CInt(Mid(cell_E6, 4, 2)) + CInt(Mid(cell_E6, 7, 4))
    End If
End If

'Finding the Actual Sales and putting into L30
If cell_B6 = "Actual Sales" Then
    ws_dash.Range("L31").Value = cell_B6
ElseIf cell_C6 = "Actual Sales" Then
    ws_dash.Range("L31").Value = cell_C6
ElseIf cell_D6 = "Actual Sales" Then
    ws_dash.Range("L31").Value = cell_D6
ElseIf cell_E6 = "Actual Sales" Then
    ws_dash.Range("L31").Value = cell_E6
End If

'BubbleSort in Descending order
Dim ArrayToSort(0 To 4) As Variant

ArrayToSort(0) = SOP_key_B6
ArrayToSort(1) = SOP_key_C6
ArrayToSort(2) = SOP_key_D6
ArrayToSort(3) = SOP_key_E6

'Moving upwards because of -1
For j = UBound(ArrayToSort) - 1 To LBound(ArrayToSort) Step -1

  'Starting at lowest
    For i = LBound(ArrayToSort) To j
      If ArrayToSort(i) > ArrayToSort(i + 1) Then
      vTemp = ArrayToSort(i)
      ArrayToSort(i) = ArrayToSort(i + 1)
      ArrayToSort(i + 1) = vTemp
      End If
    Next i
Next j

'Put sorted array into the range
'But how to put the values linked to integers?
'E.g. SOP_key_B6 = cell_B6 
 ws_dash.Range("L30:O30").Value = ArrayToSort

 End Sub
```

Most probably the solution is with replacing the array elements with the correct ones (i.e. `SOP_key_B6 = cell_B6`, etc.)?

Comment: Please explain your code. Please show us relevant parts only.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your question is.

Comment: You may wish to provide inputs, what outputs you expect those inputs to yield, and how the actual output differs. Refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks, guys, please advise if the revised description makes more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is bloated in places, for example:

```
Dim ArrayToSort(0 To 4) As Variant

ArrayToSort(0) = SOP_key_B6
ArrayToSort(1) = SOP_key_C6
ArrayToSort(2) = SOP_key_D6
ArrayToSort(3) = SOP_key_E6
```

can be replaced by

```
Dim ArrayToSort As Variant 'note lack of ()
ArrayToSort = Array(SOP_key_B6, SOP_key_C6, SOP_key_D6, SOP_key_E6)
```

As far as your question goes, it seems that you need to use a collection. Assuming that there is a one-to-one correspondence between the `SOP-key_` values and the `cell_` values (otherwise, calling them "keys" is misleading), you could do the following:

```
Dim C As New Collection
C.Add cell_B6, CStr(SOP_key_B6)
C.Add cell_C6, CStr(SOP_key_C6)
C.Add cell_D6, CStr(SOP_key_D6)
C.Add cell_E6, CStr(SOP_key_E6)
```

then, after sorting `ArrayToSort`, have a loop like:

```
For i = 0 to 3
    Range("L30").Offset(0,i).Value = C(CStr(ArrayToSort(i)))
Next i
```

I *think* this is what you are looking for -- but the code seems on the convoluted side so it might not be a bad idea to streamline it a bit.

On Edit:

You are getting duplicate keys due to the way you are constructing the keys by *adding* note that `SOP11(2015)` differs from `SOP10(2016)` but 11+2015 = 10 + 2016 (both equal to 2026). Instead -- *juxtapose*: 112015 isn't 102016.

Furthermore, it makes sense to split the key creation into its own function (so you don't repeat essentially the same code 4 times:

```
Function ExtractKey(s As Variant) As Long
    Dim v As Variant, n As Long
    v = Trim(s)
    If v Like "*(*)" Then
        n = Len(v)
        v = Mid(v, n - 7, 7)
        v = Replace(v, "(", "")
        ExtractKey = CLng(v)
    Else
        ExtractKey = 0
    End If
End Function
```

Note that the return type is `Long` -- `Integer` variables overflow too easily to be useful in VBA.

Then -- something like this should work:

```
Sub Worksheet_Delta_Update()
    Dim SourceRange As Range, TargetRange As Range
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, minKey As Long, minAt As Long
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim C As New Collection

    Set SourceRange = Worksheets("t").Range("B6:E6")
    Set TargetRange = Worksheets("t").Range("L30:O30")

    For i = 1 To 4
        v = SourceRange.Cells(1, i).Value
        C.Add Array(ExtractKey(v), v)
    Next i

    'transfer data
    For i = 1 To 4
        minAt = -1
        For j = 1 To C.Count
            If minAt = -1 Or C(j)(0) < minKey Then
                minKey = C(j)(0)
                minAt = j
            End If
        Next j
        TargetRange.Cells(1, i).Value = C(minAt)(1)
        C.Remove minAt
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: After testing a few scenarios where only 3 or 2 variables (SOP_key_b6) are fulfilled, I'm getting an error "This key is already associated with an element in this collection"...

Comment: If the keys are the same -- are the values the same? For example, can you have `SOP_key_B6 = SOP_key_C6` but `cell_B6` different from `cell_C6`? If so -- what value(s) should go in cells `L30` and `M30`?

Comment: No, I eliminated this by nesting another "If", so now every SOP_key is unique so as the value in cell_c6. I'm thinking about clearing the collection completely in beforehand adding new items to the collection. You think that's possible?

Comment: The line `Set C = New Collection` will create a new collection and assign it to `C`. The old collection will be garbage-collected. From the programmer's point of view this is equivalent to clearing `C`. Also -- you might want to look into `Dictionaries` which are like collections but a bit more flexible.

Comment: thanks, John, once again! Just tried your suggested method, but the error still appears :(

Comment: the error appears at this line `C.Add cell_E6, CStr(SOP_key_E6)`

Comment: When you encounter a key which has been used before (such as `SOP_key_6` what value do you want to store? You can't really (easily) store both `cell_E6` and the previous value corresponding to `SOP_key_E6` so the main options are either leave the old value in place (and forget about storing `cell_E6`) or replace the old value by `cell_E6`.

Comment: John, initially I thought to completely abandon the value of `SOP_key_E6` after sorting and input corresponding value of `cell_E6` in the range L31:O31. The reason I used `SOP_key_E6` because it allowed me to store integer & sort accordingly.

Comment: Le me see if I understand this -- the keys are 0 for "Actual Sales" and "XXYYY" for values of the form "SOPXX(YYYY)", these values are in B6-E6, you want to sort these according to these keys -- and put them in L30-O30? If so -- you can vastly simplify the code.

Comment: yes, absolutely correct. i much appreciate your dedication! but how would simplify it then?

Comment: thanks!! You're right about the unique capabilities of each key, I noticed that as well and hence created another nested `If` that could distinguish:  `If Mid(cell_D6, 8, 4) = "2015" Then
                SOP_key_D6 = CInt(Mid(cell_D6, 4, 2)) + CInt(Mid(cell_D6, 8, 4))
            ElseIf Mid(cell_D6, 8, 4) = "2014" Then
                SOP_key_D6 = CInt(Mid(cell_D6, 4, 2))`. <-- where 2014 assume it's 2016. Anyway, I'm gonna try the code you provided and then feedback

Comment: After few testing getting `Type mismatch error` on this line `ExtractKey = CLng(v)`. Will try to investigate

Answer (score 0):

On fixed the `Type mismatch error` with the following modificaton:

```
Function ExtractKey(s As Variant) As Long
   Dim v As Variant, n As Long
   v = Trim(s) 'remove spaces leave only spaces between words
     If v Like "*(*)" Then 'if it's SOPXX (YYYY) then
       n = Len(v) 'find number of the characters
         If n = 11 Then
           v = Mid(v, n - 7, 7) 'find the number of SOP + year in bracket
         ElseIf n = 12 Then
           v = Mid(v, n - 8, 8)
         End If
        v = Replace(v, "(", "") 'replace the brackets with nothing
        v = Replace(v, " ", "")
        ExtractKey = CLng(v) 'error WAS here
      Else
        ExtractKey = 0
      End If
End Function
```

**Edit:**
Added another few lines

```
 If n = 11 Then
         v = Right(v, 4) + Left(v, 1)
    ElseIf n = 12 Then
        v = Right(v, 4) + Left(v, 2)
    End If
```

The above switch year and number (e.g. SOP12 (2015) = 122015 and after switch 201512). This is because SOP12 (2014) was placed **after** SOP10 (2015) despite the fact it should go before as its dated year 2014. Now working like charm :)

Comment: @John the only thing now is that it places the values in the cells but skips blank (e.g. L30 = blank, M30 = blank, N30 = SOP2(2015), O30 = SOP11 (2015). Will try to fix myself but maybe you can advise?

Comment: Usually something like this belongs as an edit to the question (or perhaps an entirely new question) rather than as an answer. In any event, I don't think it would make a difference but you could replace the line `v = SourceRange.Cells(1, i)` by `v = SourceRange.Cells(1, i).Value`. Also -- `SOP2(2015)` seems to not fit the pattern of having 2 digits before the year -- it only has one.

Comment: Also -- note that `Trim` doesn't remove spaces inside the string -- just leading and trailing white space. I threw that in as a precaution since sometimes stray white spaces happen when users enter data

Comment: thanks for the forum rules! concenring the SOP2(2015) mistyped - it's SOP2 (2015). And yes, you were right, replacing the line didn't make the difference. I wonder why it skips blanks and the inputs the sorted values...